# Automator workflow for copying screenshots to clipboard

Tags: automator

I want to create an Automator Workflow that will automatically move screenshots I take with cmd+shift+3/4 to a specified folder and at the same time also copy the screenshot I took to my clipboard. I already got automator to move the files, but the action 'Copy to Clipboard' which I added, only copies the name of the file to the clipboard, not the image itself. Automator does show the selected screenshot as a result of my 'Copy to Clipboard'-action though. Any ideas how to get the screenshot I took into my clipboard with automator?

Comment: Will you please post a list of the Actions you are currently using?

Comment: I first search all the finder objects on the desktop whose file name starts with 'Screenshot...' and after that I call 'Copy to Clipboard'. The first actions finds all screenshots I have on my desktop and the 'Copy to Clipboard' actually accepts those results as well. When I go into the notes app and press cmd+v, it will insert the file names of the screenshots on my desktop, not the pictures themselves though...

Comment: So, you are actually trying to load a group of images into the clipboard, correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: OK, that will not work via Automator, or even with AppleScript.  Even though you can select multiple images via the keyboard and copy them to the clipboard, there is still no clean way to do that automatically on the Mac.  However, depending on your final destination for these images, we can certainly design an Automator workflow that will copy one image at a time and paste each one where ever you like.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It does, though I would specifically have wanted them in the clipboard. Oh well, it seems I'll have to do it the old way then. Thanks for your helpful answer!

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution [here](https://www.noodlesoft.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=4394)

I set it up so that this is a folder action that runs on my desktop folder.

```
on run {input, parameters}
   set thisFile to item 1 of input
   set the clipboard to (read thisFile as TIFF picture)
   return thisFile
end run
```

[image]

Comment: Any clue on how to run `echo myPassword | sudo -S screencapture -c -x -R1090,150,1200,720` through automator and actually have the screenshot copied to my clipboard? What I am trying right now is only working from the terminal, but not the automator-run-shell-script&system-preferences-keyboard-services-add-shortcut thingy...

Answer (score 0):

## Steps to get it all working

1. open `Automator`
2. create new `quick action`
3. in automator searchbar find `'Run Applescript'`
4. `paste` my `snippet` and modify to your liking
5. `save` / export and double click / install to services
6. `system settings > keyboard > keyboard shortcuts > screenshots > uncheck command shift 4`
7. same place as last step but go to `services tab > general` and setup keybind by double clicking right area and set to shift command shift 4

### things you may want to modify

- the **-s** tag means box **s**election so without the -s it would capture all for any psycos out there that don't like the box selection.
- the **-t** png means file extension **T**ype so it could be swapped out for -t jpg if you want to use jpg instead.
- all my steps are to swap the `command + shift + 4` keybind but you may wish another

### thing you need to modify*

- Unless your name is riley and have a folder in your pictures called Screenshots you might wish to **change** that to your name and **the folder path.**

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set screenshotFolder to "/Users/riley/Pictures/Screenshots/"
    set currentDate to do shell script "date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S'"
    set screenshotFile to screenshotFolder & "screenshot_" & currentDate & ".png"
    
    do shell script "/usr/sbin/screencapture -s -t png " & quoted form of screenshotFile
    
    return input
end run
```

My first post on overflow !!!